# Visitors don't complete registration

Tags: registration, signup-signon

A lot of visitors access the registration page, but only 46% complete the registration.

Is this a good ratio? Does anybody have any references or research that determines the ratio?

[image]

Comment: What links do they access the registration page from? Does the registration form come as a surprise? Also, how many do even start to complete that form? I think it is important to distinguish between users who for some reason give up mid-way (usability issue?) and users who decide against registering upon encountering the form (rather not usability-related in the narrow sense, this could be more an issue of your general service concept, the perceived benefit vs. cost of registering).

Comment: You would see me leaving the moment I read that mobile number is a required field.

Answer (score 5):

When asking the users for their personal details, you have to examine the use case and create a user story. Having the user journey at hand is very handy in this situation.

1. Examine how the users are landing on your page. If someone was looking for a service and they landed on a page which does not seem to provide it, they will leave/bounce to another page.
2. Some users are not willing to commit too early in the process unless there is a good reason for them to do so. Providing more information on what registering will provide is a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To address your question directly:

The conversion ratio of registration pages varies drastically between systems.

First and for most, there's the **gain/loss ratio** - what do users get for registering? A registration form on lunch on a mobile TODO list can have a conversion rate smaller than 2% - there are many similar apps out there that don't ask you to register, and you get little in return.

Sites like Facebook will experience higher conversion (people registering are often set in their mind about doing so), or sites like this one - where the service is accessible for guests, but require registration when users are already **motivated** to act - will have higher conversion rate.

Then, there's the form design itself (and many other variables, like whether people even expect a registration form, do they just want to try it out without committing personal details, and so forth).

So it's really impossible to say what's 'good' conversion rate. Nor does it matter much - your role is to improve it regardless what the baseline is.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user likely to have all the requested information on hand when completing the form?

Consider changing the field labels.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whats the form all about. Whats the website all about. Is it a  government website, or a banking site or a commercial website. Users will behave differently. The motivation and seriousness are different for all the types of websites listed above. Hence the success for completion of forms.

The success of registration forms depends on **what lies on other side**. What is it so worthy that a users would give away their mobile numbers, national IDs etc? That "**cheese**" will determine the success.

- **Registrations should be short and quick.**
- **Automatically do it for users.** (Get email ID and send them their username and temporary password, If Possible)(Popular among eCommerce websites) (Checkout without registration)
- **Help the users** as far as possible to automatically populate data

[Not much of **research data** is available](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/web-research-believe-the-data/) on this subject but it would be worthwhile to go through some information.

Answer (score 0):

It depend to the website. What it talking about?

In general, registration should be more short possible.

have you tried to change the patterns of presentation and compare the datas?
You're asking a lot of information in a single moment, many of these personal, you might be discouraged to continue.

A sign-in by step may entice the user to continue.

One way would be to "paginate" the information you ask grouping them by type of information.

Another method might be to ask only the basic information of registration and subsequently, once registered, ask to insert the missing ones.